Security tab on Chromium developer tools missing
I'm trying to track down a download speed issues on flightsim.to website. Download speeds in Firefox are 16MB/s, whereas in Chrome and Edge they are 1500 KB/s.
In Firefox dev tools I see a Security tab after Cookies on the header tools display under Network

Under Edge and Chrome I see no Security tab after Cookies. How do I change this?


It's not implemented.

Edge has a similar tab called Security and you can add it like below:


The Security tool in Edge shows similar information as Security tab in Firefox, you could check it.
